# CGI::Session Expired cookies and browser refresh

Tags: html, perl, cgi

A user enters a page in my web application. If the cookie is expired I provide the user with a link to the login page ask the user to login again. If he clicks the logout button the cookie is set to expire in the past.

```
    $cookie = $cgi->cookie(-name=>"CGISESSID",-value=>'', -path=>'/',-expires=>'-1d');
```

The cookie is being set correctly to expire in the past as seen in page info of the browser
However the page doesn't know that until I click refresh

```
my $cookie = $cgi->cookie('CGISESSID');
if ($cookie){
        #show content
}else{
        $cookie = $cgi->cookie(-name=>'CGISESSID', -expires=>'now');
        print $cgi->header(-cookie=>$cookie);
        print "Please log in again ";
        print "<a href=\"/login.html\"> Login page </a>";
}
```

How can I force the page to refresh so as to delete the cookie. If I redirect the page a simple back button will display the content even if the cookie is expired.

I have login.pl and login.js set up as in http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-simplelogin/#loginJS

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking how to force the page to refresh when you expire the cookie?

Comment: yes, or if there's a better way about it.

Comment: I think there's a bit of an X-Y problem going on here. Maybe what you really want is to send the user to a login screen as soon as the cookie expires, rather than the next time they click a link or refresh the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On logout, you can [redirect](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#GENERATING-A-REDIRECTION-HEADER) to another page:

```
$cookie = $cgi->cookie(-name=>'CGISESSID', -expires=>'now');
print $cgi->redirect(-uri => 'http://www.example.com/login', -cookie => $cookie);
```

**EDIT:** I think I misunderstood your question. It sounds like what you really want to do is redirect as soon as the cookie expires. This is tricky. Say our user's session expires, but they just leave the current page open in their browser. Unfortunately, our CGI script won't run again until the user sends another request, say by refreshing the page. And until they send a request, we won't know if their session has expired.

One possible solution is set your page to auto refresh using an HTML `<meta>` tag:

```
use CGI qw(meta);

print $q->header,
      $q->start_html(
          -head => meta( { -http_equiv => 'refresh',
                           -content => '60;URL=http://www.example.com/foo.cgi' } )
      ),
...
```

This will redirect to your CGI script every 60 seconds, allowing you to check the session again.

On another note, there are really much better tools than CGI.pm for developing web applications in Perl: [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/), [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/), and [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/), among others.

Comment: Thats the thing the Else clause is not entered until the page is refreshed

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
   print $cgi->redirect($SS1);
   # $SS1 is the url for login.html
```

Comment: Thats the thing the Else clause is not entered until the page is refreshed

Comment: not sure what you mean , the above works for me , the code is very much the same as yours : if  .... else { redirect } , why doesn't it work for you ?